# Android: Card flip inside listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I've read this article http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html and made it work, but now I want to flip like that every item in listview. Is this possible? I can't figure out how.

Comment: refer this url it will may be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688446/card-flip-in-android-list-view

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible, I've developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping.

Please have a look.